# How do we show that this modular function is one-to-one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$f(x) = {(x^2+5)}\bmod{9}$$
$${(x^2 + 5)} \bmod {9} = (x^2 + 5)\bmod 9$$
$$(x^2 + 5) = (x^2 + 5)$$
$$x^2 = x^2$$
$$x = x$$

Is this the correct way to do this?

I have no idea how to manipulate the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is **not** one to one. To show this, you need to show that there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $a\not\equiv b\pmod{9}$ but $a^2+5\equiv b^2+5\pmod{9}$. It should not take long to find such a pair $(a,b)$: there are several.

**Remark:** You can operate partly by analogy. The reason the function $x^2+5$ is not one to one in this setting is related to the reason $x^2+5$ is not one to one on the reals.

Comment: how do we manipulate x mod b = x mod b, so we end up with x=x?

Comment: @amWhy: I don't mind, but the what I had typed was a $4$ instead of a dollar sign (sticky shift key), so I had to edit to remove the $4$.

Comment: what do you mean by operate partly by analogy?

Comment: @GladstoneAsder: The problem has nothing to do with manipulating until we get to $x=x$.

Comment: On the reals, the function $f(x)=x^2+5$ is not one to one, because for example $f(-17)=f(17)$. You will find that modulo $9$, $a^2+5\equiv b^2+5$ when $a=1$ and $b=9-1=8$. We also will have same kind of result with $a=2$ and $b=7$. Also with $a=0$ and $b=3$. Also several others. So very much not one to one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are doing what I think you are doing in the second line, you should really use two different variables.  I think what you meant was $$x^2+5 \equiv y^2+5 \pmod{9}$$ $$x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod{9}$$ $$x \equiv y \pmod{9}.$$

You are on the right track, in that you are allowed to subtract 5 from both sides, but you make a mistake in saying that because $x^2 \equiv y^2,$ $x$ must be congruent to $y$.  That's not true mod 9, it's not true for reals, it's not even true for integers.

I think that more fundamentally you are asking what sorts of algebraic manipulations are valid in modular arithmetic:

- You can always add or subtract a number from both sides of an equation without affecting the validity of the statement.
- You can always replace one term of a sum or one term of a product with a congruent term.  That is, you can replace $7 \cdot 5 \pmod{3}$ with $7 \cdot 2 \pmod{3}$ because 5 and 2 are the  same thing.  This rule only applies to sums and products, however.  You can't do that with exponents, $x^5 \pmod{3}$ and $x^2 \pmod{3}$ are not the same.
- And you can multiply both sides of the equation by a constant, **only when that constant is relatively prime to the modulus**.  The caveat is very similar to the caveat with real numbers that you can't multiply by 0.  The equation remains true, but it becomes trivial.  For example, $2 \equiv 5 \pmod{6}$ is not true at all, but multiplying both sides by 2 we get $2 \cdot 2 \equiv 2 \cdot 5 \pmod{6}$ which is true.

There are of course other legal manipulations, but these are the most basic.